# How to prevent SQL Injections when inserting JSON Data in Postgres?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm new to postgres-node. Coming from a mySQL background, I'm unlearning old habits and now learning new things. I want to prevent SQL injections when inserting data. I read about [parameterized query](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#Parameterized%20query). Is this applicable to JSON type? I'm doing CRUD operations on a table in postgres that only have 2 columns. I'm manipulating JSON data (SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE). How do you prevent SQL injections when inserting JSON data in a table?

**table**

```
id | info
1  | { "customer": "John Doe", "items": {"product": "Beer","qty": 6}}'
2  | { "customer": "Lily Bush", "items": {"product": "Diaper","qty": 24}}
```

**query**

```
INSERT INTO orders (info)
VALUES('{ "customer": "Josh William", "items": {"product": "Toy Car","qty": 1}}')
```

Comment: There is no SQL injection hazard in the `INSERT` statement you quote. Perhaps you should show the code that creates the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON type is no different from other types for injection prevention:

```js
// totally wrong: concatenated unsafe input straight into the query
client.query(`INSERT INTO orders (info) VALUES (${allegedlyJsonStringifiedUserInput})`);
// totally right: parameterized query, delegating injection safeties to pg
client.query(`INSERT INTO orders (info) VALUES ($1)`, [allegedlyJsonStringifiedUserInput]);
```

Comment: Okay thanks man. I wasn't sure. I'm just inserting the whole json object as this one big value in the parameterized query haha makes my life easier. Cheers!